# Does classpath definition in Manifest.mf override or supplement library-path in EARs?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, manifest, ear

I'm having a difference of opinion with another developer (as well as empirical evidence) regarding the use of Class-Path in MANIFEST.MF.

I have an EAR with a bunch of jars in my /lib folder.  In my application.xml I have defined my `<library-path>` to be /lib, however I believe that is the default setting/value anyhow.

In my root, I have an `my-ejb.jar` file.  Within the EJB, I have a MANIFEST.MF with a Class-Path entry.

So the questions now are:

1. If a classpath entry is found in the EJB manifest, does the classloader still have access to all the jars/libs that are in /lib even if they are not explicitly specified in the manifest?
2. If no classpath entry is found in the manifest, does the EJB have access to any/all jars in /lib?
3. If a jar is specified in the manifest in a different location than /lib, does it take precedence over what is found in /lib?
4. How does a classloader resolve an issue where there are entries in the manifest for non-existant jars?
5. Are all these rules dependent on the container implementation, or are these part of the java specs somewhere (I haven't been able to find it anywhere).

Part of the issue comes up due to a third-party EJB that I am using with a Manifest that is poorly written (looking for libs in the root folder, non-existant jars, etc).  So I can rewrite the manifest, however, I also question how this would work in the case of a signed EJB jar.  Would I be able to move a dependency lib from the location as defined the the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, classloading is process specified for application server type.
In main cases it looks like this. While server search class for ear through classpath it consequently walk and search:

1. clases loaded into memory at boot time from server owned jars;
2. classes from WEB-INF for web project, if different classpath is not pointed in MANIFEST;
3. in lib folder, if it defined;

And now I'll answer your question:

1. No, if jar does not exist ClassNotFoundException would be thrown.
2. Yes.
3. Yes.
4. ClassNotFoundException would be thrown.
5. Yes, it depends from server to server. Different servers try to optimize loading procedure in different ways, and due to them we have some artefacts of project deploying and working.

You can edit MANIFEST in jar and sign it again, if you have required.

Comment: So just to confirm my understanding; if anything is listed in the manifest classpath, nothing from `<library-path>` is accessible?  Everything must be explicitly specified?  In that case, what is the advantage of specifying a manfiest classpath if I put everything in /lib?  Is there any value at all?

Comment: Yes, its rather true. If server not found jar by classpath it throw an exception. For example classpath in manifest it is needed to realize skinny war technology.